# brew install mongodb vs mongodb-community@4.0

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

The [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) say to first tap the official MongoDB formula repository:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
```

then to install mongodb-community@4.0:

```
brew install mongodb-community@4.0
```

---

Every other tutorial I see says to just install mongodb:

```
brew install mongodb
```

What's the difference? Why choose one over the other?

---

## Update

I tried installing one then uninstalling and trying the other. Here are the differences I've noticed so far:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|                             |                                           |
| brew install mongodb        | brew install mongodb-community@4.0        |
|                             |                                           |
|-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------|
| version 4.0.3               | version 4.0.9                             |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| brew services start mongodb | brew services start mongodb-community@4.0 |
| works fine.                 | gives "uninitialized constant" error      |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| mongo connects to           | mongo connects to                         |
| mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017   | mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceN |
|                             | ame=mongodb                               |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------|
| "This server is bound       | "soft rlimits too low..." warning         |
| to localhost..." warning    |                                           |
+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Sep. 2, 2019, MongoDB was removed from the Homebrew core formulas because newer versions of MondoDB are no longer published under open-source licenses. So, `brew install mongodb` should no longer be used.

The **new way of installing MongoDB** with Homebrew is to use `brew install mongodb-community@x.x`. You'll need to tap the repository maintained by the MongoDB team first. For example:

```
$ brew tap mongodb/brew
$ brew install mongodb-community@4.2
$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

Read the Homebrew team's pull request about it here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43770

MongoDB full installation instructions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score -2):

There are two different type of server 1) enterprise 2) community. Enterprise of-course is free to use for limited period of time. So that might be the difference.